# Incompatible types when returning value

Tags: java, swing

I want to display an image with drawn lines on a map, and separate images made for every single section in the image (several connected lines). I have written this code:

```
public BufferedImage getLineImage() {
    BufferedImage lineImage = null;
    BufferedImage lineImage1[]=null;
    int i=0;

    if(image != null) {
        lineImage1[i] = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),                               image.getType());

        lineImage  = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getType());

        Graphics2D g1 = lineImage1[i].createGraphics();
        Graphics2D g = lineImage.createGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));

        g1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g1.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));

        for(Section section : observeTraffic) {
            section.paintTags(g1);
            i++;
        }
        for(Section section : observeTraffic) {
            section.paintTags(g);
        }
    }

    return lineImage;
    return lineImage1;
}
```

but in the last row I get error: Incompatible types

java: incompatible types
  required: java.awt.image.BufferedImage
  found:    java.awt.image.BufferedImage[]

Can anybody help me please?

Thanks

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: You have two return statements, one returns a BufferedImage, the other returns an array of BufferedImages; the method declares it only returns a BufferedImage...and you wonder why the compilers confused...

Comment: Return type of the method is BufferedImage<br>

Answer (score 1):

`lineImage1` is defined as `BufferedImage lineImage1[]`, which is an array of BufferedImages. The return value of the method is `BufferedImage`.

You either want to change the return type to an array of `BufferedImage`s, or only return a single `BufferedImage`.

Comment: it's not either-or. two sequential return statements are compile time error ( [unreachable statement error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) )

Comment: Well, the compiler doesn't like the mis-matched return values. Once that is resolved, you are correct, two `return` statements is a problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Return type of the method is BufferedImage
But you try to return array of BufferedImage. That is thy the error occurs.
BTW: do you really have 2 return statements?

Answer (score 0):

some people may find confusing when they don't know that

```
BufferedImage lineImage1[] = null;
```

is the same as

```
BufferedImage[] lineImage1 = null;
```

and you cannot have two returns, it's illegal in Java.

So if you want to return more than one object, you can do something like

```
public Object[] getLineImage() {
(...)
    Object[] o = new Object[2];
    o[0]=lineImage;
    o[1]=lineImage1;
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you who helped me